# decompiled code is different from original code

Tags: java, decompiler

I decompiled a `.jar` file using `jd-gui` and checked codes, I found it different from original `.java` file.

- original code

  ```
  if ( total != 0 ) {
      result[ i ] = bdResult.multiply( bdItem ).divide( bdTotal, 0,
      RoundingMode.DOWN ).setScale( 0, RoundingMode.DOWN ).intValue();
  }
  ```
- decompiled code

  ```
  if (total == 0)
    continue;
  result[i] = bdResult.multiply(bdItem).divide(bdTotal, 0, 
  RoundingMode.DOWN).setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).intValue();
  ```

Why this happens?

In addition, decompiled code seems grammatically wrong( where curly bracket goes?)

Comment: if there are no curly brackets, the if statement is concluded at the first ';' that's encountered, so right behind the continue keyword

Comment: Because it's not possible to get the original source code from compiled code.

Comment: I got it how `if` statement works and can't get original code, but I still wondering `!=` is converted to `== continue;`.  This change is made by compiler?

Comment: Compiler will modify our code based on standards of coding provided to it, In this case you shouldn't use brackets. Like wise if you don't  add super class constructor it will add.

Comment: @RohanKishibe yes.

Comment: @f1sh Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to get the original code by decompiling just because different code can lead to the same java byte code statements. However, you are getting an equivalent version which performs exactly the same actions as the original.

Answer (score 1):

Decompile code always tries to do the same thing as the source code, but are written in a  different way because of the optimizations of the compiler. They are some decompiler that are better than other, check that [article](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076968/java-app-dev/java-decompilers-compared.html)

Comment: *"Decompile code always does the same thing as the source code ..."*.  Not necessarily.  Sometimes decompiled code is not valid Java.  Other times it *may* be incorrect.  A good obfuscator will do its best to *ensure* one or both of these is true.  But decompilers may get it wrong even for non-obfuscated code.